# Python and retrieving data from TeamUp using api

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to assign data from a TeamUp calendar to variables in python. My python knowledge is very limited.

Im using the TeamUp api and the python code...

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.teamup.com")

headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Teamup-Token': "XXXXXX"
}

conn.request("GET", "/ks88wezkvao5k8did2/events", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Using that code i then get the following printed in the console...

```
{'events': [{"id": "1432617207", "series_id": null, "remote_id": null, "subcalendar_id": 10797089,
             "subcalendar_ids": [10797089], "all_day": true, "rrule": "", "title": "Theatre - Inc Meal", "who": "",
             "location": "", "notes": "", "version": "083a706eb6f5", "readonly": true, "tz": null, "attachments": [],
             "start_dt": "2023-05-08T00:00:00", "end_dt": "2023-05-08T23:59:00", "ristart_dt": null,
             "rsstart_dt": null, "creation_dt": "2023-02-24T02:28:16+00:00", "update_dt": null, "delete_dt": null},
            {"id": "1502070429", "series_id": null, "remote_id": null, "subcalendar_id": 10797089,
             "subcalendar_ids": [10797089], "all_day": false, "rrule": "", "title": "Gavin", "who": "", "location": "",
             "notes": "", "version": "0d8bf6d68f24", "readonly": false, "tz": null, "attachments": [],
             "start_dt": "2023-05-08T08:30:00+01:00", "end_dt": "2023-05-08T12:30:00+01:00", "ristart_dt": null,
             "rsstart_dt": null, "creation_dt": "2023-05-02T19:01:08+01:00", "update_dt": "2023-05-02T19:01:11+01:00",
             "delete_dt": null}, {"id": "1501983305", "series_id": null, "remote_id": null, "subcalendar_id": 10797089,
                                  "subcalendar_ids": [10797089], "all_day": false, "rrule": "",
                                  "title": "Findley Close", "who": "", "location": "Findlay Cl Gillingham ME8 9HA",
                                  "notes": "", "version": "a081d79a6812", "readonly": false, "tz": "Europe\/London",
                                  "attachments": [], "start_dt": "2023-05-08T13:00:00+01:00",
                                  "end_dt": "2023-05-08T14:00:00+01:00", "ristart_dt": null, "rsstart_dt": null,
                                  "creation_dt": "2023-05-02T17:24:19+01:00", "update_dt": "2023-05-02T19:00:57+01:00",
                                  "delete_dt": null},
            {"id": "1501983352", "series_id": null, "remote_id": null, "subcalendar_id": 10797089,
             "subcalendar_ids": [10797089], "all_day": false, "rrule": "", "title": "Gregory Close", "who": "",
             "location": "Gregory Cl Gillingham ME8 9LJ", "notes": "", "version": "b2e45e9e88dd", "readonly": false,
             "tz": "Europe\/London", "attachments": [], "start_dt": "2023-05-08T14:30:00+01:00",
             "end_dt": "2023-05-08T15:30:00+01:00", "ristart_dt": null, "rsstart_dt": null,
             "creation_dt": "2023-05-02T17:24:22+01:00", "update_dt": "2023-05-02T19:00:54+01:00", "delete_dt": null},
            {"id": "1501983372", "series_id": null, "remote_id": null, "subcalendar_id": 10797089,
             "subcalendar_ids": [10797089], "all_day": false, "rrule": "", "title": "Ferrier Close", "who": "",
             "location": "Ferrier Cl Gillingham ME8 9JL", "notes": "", "version": "18fc1637e29e", "readonly": false,
             "tz": "Europe\/London", "attachments": [], "start_dt": "2023-05-08T15:30:00+01:00",
             "end_dt": "2023-05-08T16:30:00+01:00", "ristart_dt": null, "rsstart_dt": null,
             "creation_dt": "2023-05-02T17:24:25+01:00", "update_dt": "2023-05-02T19:00:51+01:00", "delete_dt": null},
            {"id": "1496199581", "series_id": null, "remote_id": null, "subcalendar_id": 10797089,
             "subcalendar_ids": [10797089], "all_day": false, "rrule": "", "title": "Lottie Prudence", "who": "",
             "location": "William Street", "notes": "", "version": "aa118772e8e5", "readonly": false,
             "tz": "Europe\/London", "attachments": [], "start_dt": "2023-05-08T17:00:00+01:00",
             "end_dt": "2023-05-08T18:00:00+01:00", "ristart_dt": null, "rsstart_dt": null,
             "creation_dt": "2023-04-26T21:19:00+01:00", "update_dt": "2023-05-04T02:06:27+01:00", "delete_dt": null}],
 'timestamp': 1683509960}
```

How can i assign the `title`, `start_dt`, `end_dt` to variables.

I have tried to use the pyTeamUp package but wasnt able to figure out how to get the data. What i would like to be able to do is display a list of the calendar items for each sub calendar in an app built using kivy. Once i can store the data in variables, i can use it in kivy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
import http.client
import json
from datetime import datetime

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.teamup.com")

headers = {
    'Accept': "application/json",
    'Teamup-Token': "XXXXXX"
}

conn.request("GET", "/ks88wezkvao5k8did2/events", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

response_dict = json.loads(data)

for event in response_dict.get("events", []):
    title = event['title']
    start = event['start_dt']
    end = event['end_dt']

    # Convert 08-05-2023 18:00:00 format
    start_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(start).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    end_dt = datetime.fromisoformat(end).strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Print the event information
    print(f"Title: {title}, Start Date: {start_dt}, End Date: {end_dt}")
```

Comment: That gives me a much more readable output. I just need to see how i can assign them to variables. Thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer.  For each event, assign the corresponding values to the `title`, `start`, and `end` variables.

Comment: Welcome. Hope it will be the accepted solution.

Comment: I wonder if you could help me a little more please.
How can i make the start and end dates  a usable format.  Currently they are 
2023-05-08T18:00:00+01:00 but i would like them to be 08-05-2023 18:00:00. I tried to use rstrip and strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") but just cannot seem to get it right.
Thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pprint import pprint

# PREVIOUS CODE HERE

x = data.decode("utf-8")

# pretty print dict to human readable format
pprint(x)

# then, it's obvious:
title    = x['events'][0]['title']
start_dt = x['events'][0]['start_dt']
end_dt   = x['events'][0]['end_dt']
```

Comment: Thank you, but i get the following error with that code.
  File "W:\TDGApp\events.py", line 23, in <module>
    for e in x['events']:
             ~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Refresh and try again

Comment: Sorry, still getting the same error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\TDGApp\events.py", line 23, in <module>
    title    = x['events'][0]['title']
               ~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Try `x[0]['events'][0]['title']`

Comment: Same error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "W:\TDGApp\events.py", line 24, in <module>
    x[0]['events'][0]['title']
    ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Comment: Try to do `pprint(x)` and post a line with `title`, or better, use https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin

Comment: That dosen't give an error. I still dont know how to assign them to variables though.